# Floor space per occupant distribution - changes over time

Tags: housing

Where could I find statistics on the floor space per occupant as a function of wealth (or income) - preferably for the UK but any country with a reasonably high population density would do.

The closest I found so far is the following chart from [this report looking at housing in the UK](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/airdrive-images/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/20210224092900/Housing-Research-Note-6-An-analysis-of-housing-floorspace-per-person.pdf). There appears to be a relationship between the lines in green and yellow where it shows that people with mortgages have gradually been getting more and more space while people that are renting are getting less and less. This isn't exactly what I was looking for but one might assume that people with mortgages are generally wealthier that people renting so it's close.

What I would really like is a similar graph but instead of the categories being "people with mortgages"/"people renting" they were instead "People in the top tenth percentile of wealth" / "People in the bottom tenth percentile of wealth" - or similar.

[image]

Comment: you should not delete and spam reposts of old closed question. You can always edit your question and it can be reopened by users

Comment: I had thought that once a question had been closed for a few days then, even if edited, almost nobody would see it anymore - am I wrong about that? I don't know exactly how SO works with regard sorting questions but I assume it would just get buried a long way down the list.

Comment: yes you are wrong on that. Every time you edit question gets bumped on top of the que on active questions for about a day. If not enough people vote reopen it is likely that it is because they still find some problem with your post so you should try to do another edit that tries to fix the original reason for closing.

Comment: I know you are very keen to ensure I don't show the tiniest hint of actually expressing an opinion - so how about this new ultra-bland edit. Any complaints now?

Comment: 1. I am not keen on anything except on following the rules of SE, rules you agreed to when you created your account, because that is my job. 2. I didnt close your question, community closed it. You got 3 close votes from various members of community (none of which were by any of the mods) and the reason they voted was that the question needs details or clarity.